# How to provide secure communication between client & server?

Tags: http, ssl, https, jetty

I'm creating a web server using Jetty (v9) and I need any traffic between browsers and the server to be encrypted. I'll be uploading files to the server, plus the client/server will maintain a session carrying sensitive access tokens.

I don't have much experience with web servers, but it seems like the solution is to have the web server serve on port 443 so that communication will use the HTTPS protocol.

I was going to start running through [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html) for configuring Jetty with SSL, but before I start messing around with certificates and signing etc. I just wanted to ask if this is the right approach or if there is something else more suitable that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, using https is indeed the right approach.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know.